# How to get relative cell (offset(current_cell;0;-1) when using BYCOL

Tags: google-sheets, offset

[image]

I'm trying to get current relative left cell, how can I address it?

I've got a formula like  `BYCOL(A1:P1;LAMBDA(cells;IF(isblank(OFFSET(cells;0;0));;if(isblank(offset(cells;0;-1));cells&char(10)&1;index(split(offset("I_NEED_TO_GET_CURRENT_CELL";0;-1);char(10);1;2)+1)))))`

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1k0kznBnPSS-qwJsZHPlwtLTq00T2jUo8HU6teUrjNco/edit#gid=0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*(Note that your BYCOL here is equivalent to MAP since you are providing a one-dimensional array)*

Trying to get the offset of the cell is not the best way to solve this problem, I proposed a solution with SCAN:

```
=SCAN(;1:1;LAMBDA(a;c;IF(c="";;c&CHAR(10)&REGEXREPLACE(a;"(?m)\D+$";)+1)))
```